# Close an activity after a defined time period

Tags: java, android, android-activity, time, android-timer

I want to start an activity and store the start time in a variable, suppose session variable and check every second for a duration of 30 minutes. The moment it elapses 30 minutes the activity will close.

Comment: do you want the activity itself or the initiater to stop the activity?

Comment: activity itself should close, problem is not regarding activity, it is regarding how to count time in background ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CountDownTimer`

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { //time in miliseconds

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     view.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("here close your activity");
 }
}.start();
```

It is not mentioned in the decantation but you may need to consider how to handle the task if it is in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Handler for that as below:

```
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    };
    int MINUTES = 30;
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000 * 60 * MINUTES);
```

If you want to remove callbacks of Runnable.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

Hope it will helps you..

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
int finishTime = 30000; 
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        YourActivity.this.finish();
    }
}, finishTime * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
function hideActivity(){
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
    this.finish();
   }
  }, TIME_TAKEN_TO_BE_HIDDEN);
}
```